# Is there a way to see if a function is done executing?

Tags: javascript, function, html5-canvas

I have a class with many objects, and I need to see if the function for each of these objects is done being executed.

I have tried using an array, where I keep track of each function's status, but it's pretty inefficient. Are there any other ways to do this?

The objects are for dialogue in a small game I'm making.

This is the example of the code I have right now:

```
var functionExecuted = [false, false, false, false, false, false];
```

The function in the class takes a parameter of where the object's function is in the array. At the end of the function in the class, I do this:

```
functionExecuted[this.funcExecutedIndex] = true;
```

And then later once the function is finished executed, I continue on with the program

The reason why I have to check for this is because I'm working with the HTML canvas, and if I don't wait for the function to finish being executed, it draws on top of it.

Comment: What's inefficient about it?

Comment: Please show some example code so we can better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Because I have a lot of objects, and each object uses a function, it's going to be really annoying to check if  the functions have been completed, since I'll have to repeat the code multiple times over and over again.

Comment: You could use a `Set` to keep track instead of having to maintain indexes..

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to write a wrapper function that, given a function name, creates a wrapper for it that adds the execution status to a `Set`. The overhead would be marginal at best.

Comment: This might be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) as it's a rather unusual pattern/request. Are you looking for `Promise.all()` if the funcs are async? If not, why "check" instead of simply running the code you want to run after calling the funcs synchronously using the normal call stack and control flow? What's the context/use case exactly?

Comment: I'm using a dialogue for a tiny game I'm making, and the letters appear one by one on the screen, so it takes time to finish calling it. I didn't know that Promise.all() is a function though, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

functions in JS are just objects, as such you can store them in a Set.

The nice thing about using a Set's, it avoids you having to maintain that `funcExecutedIndex`, and you can use it to find out if a particular function has been executed, and it's size can be used to check if all functions have been executed..

Below is a simple example.

```js
class Procs {
  executed = new Set();
  one() {
    this.executed.add(this.one);
  }
  two() {
    this.executed.add(this.two);
  }
  whatsExecuted() {
    console.log('one executed: ' + this.executed.has(this.one));
    console.log('two executed: ' + this.executed.has(this.two));
  }
  allExecuted() {
    return this.executed.size === 2;
  }
}


const procs = new Procs();
procs.whatsExecuted();
console.log('---');

procs.one();
procs.whatsExecuted();
console.log('all done: ' + procs.allExecuted());

console.log('---');

procs.two();
procs.whatsExecuted();
console.log('all done: '+ procs.allExecuted());
```